# How to use Azure App to send email on users behalf?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-graph-api, user-permissions

I try to send an email on users behalf from Azure Web App using Open Graph. Email has to be sent using office365 mail server and should be saved in users *Sent* mailbox. Mentioned App can be accessed by authorized users only, authorization is performed with the use of below endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tennantid}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri={domain}.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id={clientId}&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post
```

Once user logs in, I fetch access token for further requests to Open Graph:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tennantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type  "client_credentials"
client_secret   "{clientSecret}"
client_id   "{clientId}"
scope   "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
```

Next, I post to sendMail endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
```

and pass necessary parameters, as well as `authorization Bearer {accessToken}` header where accessToken was retrieved in previous step. This returns an error:

```
"code":"NoPermissionsInAccessToken","message":"The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood."
```

As for permissions, app has delegated permissions set up for mail.send so that it can send emails on behalf of logged in user only. App does not ask user for permissions when logging in, ther are no consents presented.

I have no more ideas how to make it work after digging into documentations and spending there quite some time so any tip will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the Client Credential grant type you will be getting the App token and you need to have application token set for it.

The API doesn't know what is the meaning of /me here since its a client credential flow.

If you want to use client credential flow then to send mail you need to specify the call this way.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{Userid/UPN}/sendMail](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUserid/UPN%7D/sendMail)

So please add Mail.Send Application permission in you App in Azure as shown in the below screenshot and then make the above call.

[image]

You can also verify whether you are have permissions or not by using your access token at [JWT site](https://jwt.ms).

Comment: What if I don't want to grant applicacton permissions to send as any user? Is there another solution in such case?

Comment: @jacek_podwysocki To send mail on behalf of any user you should use Application permissions, if you use delegated permissions you need to use User context flows like Authorization code flow etc., and the user need to signin and after that the mail will be sent on behalf of the signed in user and you will be using the call as /me/sendMail in this case.